# State Machine Memory Management Problems

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

My state machine handles requests and returns the next state. In the below simplification, I've got two states here, `CreatedState` and `RunningState`. Running state is the end state, and just returns itself. Running state has state (as in memebers) that need to be preseved, I'll use the integer `count` to represent them.

```
std::unique_pointer<StateBase> handle();

// Caller
void Call(){
    _currentState = _currentState->handle();
}

// Created State Implementation
std::unique_pointer<StateBase> CreatedState::handle(){
    return std::make_unique<RunningState>();
}

// Running State Implementation (option 1: create a new one)
std::unique_pointer<StateBase> RunningState::handle(){
    return std::make_unique<RunningState>(RunningState(int count));
}
```

The problem here is that creating a new `RunningState` with a memento/all-of-the-private-members of the old `RunningState` is messy and probably inefficient(?).

In a managed language I might just `return this`, but if I did something like that: `return std::make_unique<RunningState>(&this)` I would have two pointers to the same object and the destruction of the lhs `_currentState` in the `Call()` would leave me with nothing to point at.

How can I cleanly and efficiently leave `_currentState` unchanged?

Comment: The [`std::enable_shared_from_this` base class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) was originally designed to solve problems similar to this. However, I have yet to see practical use of it, so I can't comment on its efficacy.

Comment: `std::make_unique<...>(this)` does not merely *point to the same object*. It forwards the arguments to the *constructor* of the class, effectively *copy-constructing* another instance, taking your argument instance as the *source of data*. If you do not define any constructors for your class, C++ will [implicitly define](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) one for you.

Comment: @rwong Good point about the shared, might be the way to go. I do sort of feel that with reference counting pointers I'll be paying for a lot I don't use as well as allowing for slopper ownership by code calling my state machine (maybe that's a bad thing?). I see that my (this) C++ code is wrong, and probably still is, my State classes contain unique pointers and cannot be copied anyway.

Comment: It seems you should just treat your design as usual polymorphism (or, non-polymorphism, if there's nothing in common), since it is unclear to me why you need to advance to next-state from a RunningState. In other words,  the CreatedState has a reason to advance to next-state which is RunningState, but RunningState doesn't.

Comment: @rwong I don't think it's necessarily wrong to have a state machine with an end state. I understand how my simplified example doesn't really do that argument justice, however. I think I'll probably seek some more feedback from SO.CR about that when I'm done. Thanks for your help rwong.

Answer (score 1):

My potential solution:

Pass the pointer as a reference. Alter it in the handle as needed. I'm not a big fan of mutating parameters in general, but I think this might be the way to go?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void handle2(std::unique_ptr<int>& current, bool changePtr)
{
    *current = *current + 5 ;
    if(changePtr){
    auto foo = std::make_unique<int>(200);
    (*foo)++;
    current = std::move(foo); //destruction of current only happens if I want to change state
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto currentState = std::make_unique<int>(50);

    handle2(currentState, false);
    std::cout << *currentState << std::endl; // 55
    // Guard against nullptr in caller      

    handle2(currentState, true);  
    std::cout << *currentState << std::endl; // 201

    handle2(currentState, false);    
    std::cout << *currentState << std::endl; // 206
}
```

Incidently, here is the state machine I was designing:
https://github.com/mikeyjkmo/ableton-freetime-looper